# What are alternative agile applications?

Tags: scrum, agile, kanban

Agile is getting more popular by the minute and as i understand it is all due to expanding the practice into new areas and business fields. I am interested in knowing what other fields, outside of software development, is agile being used in and how does it benefit them?

Comment: I believe that you can find an answer to your question here: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/agile-methodologies-such-as-scrum-in-non-software-development-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, I have found that agile can be easily adapted to most of the traditional business fields, such as **finance and marketing**.

An example I came about most recently is a **kanban application within an accounting firm**:

Prior to kanban being introduced, the firm was doing okay, but it lacked structure and capabilities to distribute the work and track resources effectively.

Applying the practice solved that by visualizing the work on the kanban board. All the team members immediately saw the full scope and structure of work to be completed.

It also allowed the team to move away from the traditional model where one accountant is responsible for certain clients and to distribute their resources more evenly to be the most productive.

Lastly, by tracking the work in such way they were able to say exactly how much time was needed for each client and make more accurate future estimations.

Answer (score 1):

There is a real appetite from the Scrum Alliance and various stakeholders to push Scrum into new industries including Construction (Scrum-C).

You can find one such example here https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2015/may/scrum-in-construction-(1)

The Agile Coffee podcast touches upon this issue every few episodes and is a worthy listen.